# Symfony2 serializer not working sometimes

Tags: json, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

Here is my controller. For the most part it works great, and returns a nice JSON object for me. But on some entities it just hangs on the line indicated below. The completion of the data in my entities varies, and there doesn't seem to be a connection between a specific field being missing and the serialization not working

Also, my normal view works perfectly, it just seems to be the serializer not working correctly.

Has anyone else had problems with Symfony's built in serializer?

**Edit:** took a deeper look and it looks like I'm using the JMSSerializerBundle for this.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('inertia');

    $entity = $em->getRepository('InertiaBundle:Accounts')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Accounts entity.');
    }


    if($format == 'json') {
        // return json array
        $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
        $data = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json'); //hangs at this line.

        $response = new Response($data);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    } else {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        return $this->render('InertiaBundle:Accounts:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to expose/exclude your Entity attributes? http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. It's been about a year since I was working on this though. I believe I just ditched the serializer and did it manually. This was actually better for me in this case, because I needed some fields not to show up in the json response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the request hanging on the following line:

```
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
```

Replacing it with the following seemed to work

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
```

I don't yet know enough Symfony2 to know why this is the case but maybe someone more knowledgeable than me can explain.